# Ruby on Rails: comparison of values in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using this [example for uploading files in Ruby on Rails.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
I have some problems with the uploads/index.html.erb

I have some more variables like:
current_user.id - id of a user how is now online
user_id         - user_id in a upload table, so it just like a foreign key, to assign several uploads to one user.

So, I want to list only those uploads, whose user_id corresponds to current_user.id. I try to do it in this line

```
((({%=file.user_id%}).to_i)==((<%=current_user.id%>).to_i))
```

Somehow it does not work, as uploads, whose user_id does not correspond to current_user.id, are listed as well.

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">

  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  {% if ((({%=file.user_id%}).to_i)==((<%=current_user.id%>).to_i)){ %} 
    <tr class="template-download fade">    

      <td class="l">
       <a href="{%=file.url%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.user_id%}</a>
      </td>
      <td class="k">
       <a href="{%=file.url%}" download="{%=file.name%}"><%=current_user.id%></a>
      </td>  


      <td class="name">
       <a href="{%=file.url%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
      </td>

       <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"> 
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>

        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>



       <td></td>


    </tr>
{% } %}


    {% } %}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't get the syntax. the for loop looks like a javascript code but the if uses to_i outside of {% } whatever that is.

Comment: jeah. it is a javascript + i tried to put some ruby syntax in oder to do comparison

Comment: to_i is in ruby convert to integer, isnt it?

Comment: it is. but with your code, it's hard to imagine whether the code is being run in erb or in the template.  can i edit the brackets?

Comment: of course, feel free to do it

Comment: Hm...is it not better to load from database only uploads with corresponding user_id?

Comment: It is, but I am quite new to ruby/javascript and therefore I have no idea how to do it in a javascript. Or do you mean, I should avoid javascript and do it only using ruby and rails?

Comment: I posted it as answer) too much text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch uploads in controller smth. like

```
@files = Upload.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

or if your `User` model `has_many :uploads` you can make

```
@files = current_user.uploads
```

then in @files variable in views you'll have only uploads corresponding to `current_user`

Comment: I did a bit differently, but you has_many gave me a good idea=) thanks